# Good Example of User/Application Authentication Using ExtJS 4 and MVC?

Tags: security, model-view-controller, extjs4, authentication

I'm looking for a solid example of user authentication in an ExtJS 4 MVC application. Don't get me wrong, I can easily create a login form that, after a user is authenticated, destroys and then recreates a viewport with the appropriate application view in it but I'm not sure this is the best approach.

How do you balance application security with the idea that the application only has one view (the page never physically changes URL's)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a login.php that has a basic login form.  On login, validate the user, log that the user is authenticated and then re-direct to an index.php which would load your ExtJs web application.  In your index.php file, only load the ExtJs application if you can verify the user is authenticated.

I found this: http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

In the tutorial they re-direct to login_success.php, this would be your index.php.  You can see, it checks to see if the user is logged in.

```
// Check if session is not registered , redirect back to login page. 
// Put this code in first line of your index.php 
<? 
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: I would specifically *not* suggest this. This encapsulates authentication (is the u/p correct and what roles does this person have) with binary authorization (the user is allowed access to everything or nothing).  Successful applications require finer granularity than this, meaning some functionality is partially or fully available depending on a user's role, and this can't be managed in this manner.

Comment: This is an example.  Goes without saying it is not a wholesale solution that will work for everyone.  But, to say it can't be managed in this manner... I disagree.  You can add whatever logic you would like in the index.php including handling user roles.

Answer (score 1):

In our project we authenticate user on the server using ASP.NET membership providers. Do you want to use server side auth or something else?

Comment: Authentication for us is run to the backend (PHP). What I'm looking for is an example of how the frontend flows together.

Comment: Depends of what are you trying to achieve? Don't show to non-authenticated user your code? Or disable access to some data based on the permissions?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent unauthenticated users from seeing my application code / using my application.

Comment: Then you need to separate two pieces (your app and login page) somehow. It wasn't a problem for us. We assumed that user can have access to the app code, and even can modify it - we just check his permissions on the server and allow him to do only what he's allowed to.

Comment: So you basically had two app.js files? The first app.js was just the "app" for the authentication screen / other non-authenticated content. once the user logs in they're redirected to a _complete_ _different_ page with a different app.js file that shows authenticated content?

Comment: No need to have two app.js files, just have a login.html or login.php that handles the login and re-directs to the app on authentication.  Your app will just check all incoming requests to make sure the user is authenticated.

Comment: @justin can you update your comment as an answer with a better description of what you're doing? I understand it, but it needs to be an answer for me to accept.